# Garbage values when accessing public member variable

Tags: c++

Please bear with me I'm a novice at C++ , [This is the code](http://ideone.com/YHoRDw) (pastebin backup is below) I've written for solving the eight puzzle problem.

I'm instantiating an object here in `main.cpp`

```
State initial(intial,0);
initial.setHeuristic(goal);
initial.setfN(initial);
```

Now when I print this I get the result as I expected, however, when I pass it to the `nextState(State astate)` function and try to print it its completely different.

```
int cost = astate.cost; //In class State, This isn't the same one as it appeared previously!
```

When I executed it in ideone the result was:

```
012
345
678
cost= 0heuristic= 4total= 4
printing astate                   //Its the previous state 
012
345
678
cost= -1217288744heuristic= 134552700total= 134544434  //Its now completely transformed!
```

As you can see the numbers are now completely different!
I can't figure out why and completely marooned, Please help.

[pastebin backup](http://pastebin.com/3d23khsE)

Comment: reduce it to a **minimal but complex example** that others can compile and try out, post that

Comment: Also, find better names to make it more visually distinct: `goal` vs. `gol`, `initial` vs. `intial`.

Comment: Couldn't be bothered to include the relevant code in your question eh?

Comment: You may use *const reference* to avoid all those object copies...

Comment: Also printState is a utility function and not a class method.. if you want private members make it a friend or make it a static method instead..

Comment: sorry about that Alf and Oblivious, i was too much confused.Jarod42 Can you please explain how i may do that?

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna: something like: http://ideone.com/m6OSF5

Comment: Thanks Jarod, Forgive my ignorance,  I just learnt the syntax and started coding it. Can you please explain what does this `const State&` actually mean? Isn't const meant for constant values? How does adding that change anything?

Comment: You can learn more about minimal but complex here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call implicitly `State(vector<vector<int>> sState)` here:

```
initial.nextState(intial); // intial != initial.
```

This is equivalent to:

```
initial.nextState(State(intial)); // implicit constructor.
```

And `State(vector<vector<int>> sState)` doesn't initialize cost.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out, i used the other one constructor for representing a goal state, which doesn't have any cost.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your objects are passed by value, which means a new object is created whenever you pass a `State` object to a function like `printState` or `nextState`. You need to change these functions to take a reference.

In addition, it looks like both `printState` and `nextState` should either be static method of the `State` class or stand-alone functions. They don't use the object state so what's the point of doing this:

```
initial.printState(initial);
tempHolder = initial.nextState(intial);
```

If can be (if you make them stand-alone):

```
printState(initial);
tempHolder = nextState(intial);
```

or (if you make them static)

```
State::printState(initial);
tempHolder = State::nextState(intial);
```

Comment: Thanks Marius i'll do the changes.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks more like java then c++ because you pass objects by value; which from a syntax point of view is the same as passing them by reference in Java.

What that means is that a local copy of your object is created when a function is called and destructed when you exit the function. So you cannot save values between function calls of expect a function to do something based on the execution of a different one just because they are passed the same object.

Using references should help;